# Need help exiting a IEnumerator when the player moves

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've had a good look around and tried different methods to achieve this but I'm not getting the right results. I know I'm asking a lot but I've ran into a brick wall with this one and would appreciate some help if you could.

When the player is mining a resource I would like it to stop mining if they move from their starting position. I've posted the full class so you can see what I'm doing and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mining : MonoBehaviour, IInteractable
{
    private Coroutine gatherRoutine;
    private Vector3 playerPosition;

    [SerializeField]
    private float timeToGather;

    [SerializeField]
    private LootTable lootTable;

    [SerializeField]
    [Tooltip("Leave blank if there is no achievement attached to this object")]
    private string achievementName;

    [Header("Interaction Cursor")]
    [SerializeField]
    private float interactDistance;

    [SerializeField]
    private Texture2D cursorTexture;

    [SerializeField]
    private CursorMode cursorMode = CursorMode.Auto;

    [SerializeField]
    private Vector2 hotSpot = Vector2.zero;

    private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        if ((Vector3.Distance(Player.MyInstance.MyTransform.position, transform.position) < interactDistance) && !Player.MyInstance.MyIsGathering)
        {
            Cursor.SetCursor(cursorTexture, hotSpot, cursorMode);
            Player.MyInstance.MyInteractable = GetComponent<IInteractable>();
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.SetCursor(null, Vector2.zero, cursorMode);
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        Cursor.SetCursor(null, Vector2.zero, cursorMode);
    }

    public void Interact()
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(Player.MyInstance.MyTransform.position, transform.position) < interactDistance && Player.MyInstance.MyHasPickaxe == true)
        {
            playerPosition = Player.MyInstance.MyTransform.position;
            gatherRoutine = StartCoroutine(Gather(timeToGather));
        }
        else
        {
            GameManager.MyInstance.SendMessageToChat("You need to equip a 'Pickaxe' to mine this resource.", Message.MessageType.warning);
        }
    }

    public void StopInteract()
    {
        Player.MyInstance.MyIsGathering = false;
        Player.MyInstance.animator.SetBool("Mining", Player.MyInstance.MyIsGathering);

        if (gatherRoutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(gatherRoutine);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Gather(float time)
    {
        Player.MyInstance.MyIsGathering = true;
        Player.MyInstance.animator.SetBool("Mining", Player.MyInstance.MyIsGathering);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

        Player.MyInstance.MyIsGathering = false;
        Player.MyInstance.animator.SetBool("Mining", Player.MyInstance.MyIsGathering);

        lootTable.ShowLoot();

        if (achievementName != null)
        {
            AchievementManager.MyInstance.EarnAchievement(achievementName);
        }

        Destroy(gameObject);
        Cursor.SetCursor(null, Vector2.zero, cursorMode);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try `StopAllCoroutines()`?

Comment: what calls `StopInteract()`?

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?  I'll just say an alternative way to implement state machines in unity, since you are already setting state into the animator, is to use a StateMachineBehavior.

Comment: I don't think implementing this kind of logic with coroutines is a good idea. It's the simpler way, but it'll give you too mnay headaches later on. I'd recommend state machines as well.

Comment: Should I use OnStateMove or OnStateUpdate?

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop a Coroutine with exactly the same parameter as starting it.

From [StopCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html):

> StopCoroutine takes one of three arguments which specify which coroutine is stopped:
>
> - A string function naming the active coroutine
> - The IEnumerator variable used earlier to create the coroutine.
> - The Coroutine to stop the manually created Coroutine.
>
> **Note**: Do not mix the three arguments. If a string is used as the argument in StartCoroutine, use the string in StopCoroutine. Similarly, use the IEnumerator in both StartCoroutine and StopCoroutine. Finally, use StopCoroutine with the Coroutine used for creation.

So you should assign `gatherRoutine` beforehand

```
gatherRoutine = Gather(timeToGather);
StartCoroutine(gatherRoutine);
```

and than later

```
StopCoroutine(gatherRoutine);
```

---

Alternatively you could either use `StopAllCoroutines()` to stop the coroutine without having to handle the parameter (should only be used if there is only one Coroutine in that class).

```
public void StopInteract()
{
    Player.MyInstance.MyIsGathering = false;
    Player.MyInstance.animator.SetBool("Mining", Player.MyInstance.MyIsGathering);

    if (gatherRoutine != null)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }
}
```

---

Or you could use a bool and do

```
private interuptRoutine = false;

public void Interact()
{
    if (Vector3.Distance(Player.MyInstance.MyTransform.position, transform.position) < interactDistance && Player.MyInstance.MyHasPickaxe == true)
    {
        playerPosition = Player.MyInstance.MyTransform.position;
        // before starting the routine set the interupt flag to false
        interuptRoutine = false;
        StartCoroutine(Gather(timeToGather));
    }
    else
    {
        GameManager.MyInstance.SendMessageToChat("You need to equip a 'Pickaxe' to mine this resource.", Message.MessageType.warning);
    }
}

public void StopInteract()
{
    Player.MyInstance.MyIsGathering = false;
    Player.MyInstance.animator.SetBool("Mining", Player.MyInstance.MyIsGathering);

    if (gatherRoutine != null)
    {
        // only set the interupt flag
        interuptRoutine = true;
    }
}

private IEnumerator Gather(float time)
{
    Player.MyInstance.MyIsGathering = true;
    Player.MyInstance.animator.SetBool("Mining", Player.MyInstance.MyIsGathering);

    // does the same as WaitForSeconds but manually and interupts the routine
    // if interuptRoutine was set to true
    var timePast = 0;
    while(timePast <= time)
    {
        if(interuptRoutine) yield brake;
        timePast += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    

    Player.MyInstance.MyIsGathering = false;
    Player.MyInstance.animator.SetBool("Mining", Player.MyInstance.MyIsGathering);

    lootTable.ShowLoot();

    if (achievementName != null)
    {
        AchievementManager.MyInstance.EarnAchievement(achievementName);
    }

    Destroy(gameObject);
    Cursor.SetCursor(null, Vector2.zero, cursorMode);
}
```

Comment: Why not `StopCoroutine(gatherRoutine)`?